# TYPO3 migration

Tags: migration, typo3

I need migrate TYPO3 website to different server. My client gave me MySQL database and these files and folder for TYPO3 migration :

```
vendor
.htaccess
_.htaccess
composer.json
composer.lock
CONTRIBUTING.md
ChangeLog
index.php
INSTALL.md
```

Can you please help me how can I migrate website with these files? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure you got familiar with TYPO3 and composer already. What have you tried so far and where is your actual problem?

Comment: If this is a working page, the document root is missing. I see no folder which should contain `fileadmin` and `typo3conf`. Sure that this is complete?

Comment: Thank you guys. I made until now only one typo3 migration. In this case I had more files: fileadmin, typo3, typo3conf, typo3temp, uploads, .htaccesss, index.php. Now I haven't these files. I have only vendor folder and some files, how I wrote. My question is, if can I make migration only with these files. For example with clear TYPO3 installation.

Comment: You could accept one of the answers if they helped to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

guessing from the comments, it seems that at least the folders "fileadmin" and "typo3conf" are missing!

So your migration is impossible to finish at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

After getting aware about the issue you are having is: you are going to make a fresh installation migration of TYPO3, and for this you can migrate on server all files and process your installation there, and

if you are thinking to migrate after installation than you can just copy all files change your DB credential in /typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php

```
'DB' => array(
    'database' => 'YOURDBNAME',
    'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'password' => 'YOURPASSWORD',
    'port' => 3306,
    'username' => 'YOURDBUSERNAME',
)
```

and change config.baseurl in your setup TypoScript.

```
config.baseURL= https://www.example.com
```

Comment: thank you very much! you're right. I had wrong files.